# How can I reintroduce autocompletion of Gutenberg components in Visual Code?

Tags: block-editor, autocomplete

I have a development environment in Visual Code, in which I have a WordPress Theme, in which a Webpack process is watching my code changes through the integrated terminal.

This process uses `@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin` as a plugin in the Webpack process.

Until the past few days, typing the initial part of a component like `<Inspect`... (for `<InspectorControls>`) would autocomplete and automatically pull in the component reference to the top of the JS file.

```
import { InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
```

This would also allow me to hover over `InspectorControls` to see its attributes.

Now, without knowingly having changed anything, this isn't working. My questions are:

1. Where does this intelligent autocompletion come from?
2. How can I reinstate it?
3. Is an extension providing this functionality? I've reinstalled intelliphense but this seems to have no beneficial effect.

Comment: The JS/TS intellisense functionality is inherently provided by VSCode's core systems (by default, anyway). If you're importing the functionality from a locally installed package, it should be able to provide the mentioned context, assuming you haven't changed Webpack's module resolution strategy to something peculiar or some such. You may need to enquire in VSCode's support channels. Short of other solutions, you may need to explicitly set up [a `jsconfig` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript) to inform VSCode's JS functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would install the packages into your project. That will give you the auto-complete you're looking for:

`npm install @wordpress/block-editor`

This package will not be bundled with your JS as the dependency extraction plugin converts the references to access them on the `wp` global.

Comment: Thanks: that's how I've been doing it since integrating `@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin` to the Webpack process some time ago.